# How do I install Spreadsheet Freezer?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-addons, spreadsheet-freezer

I have hear that Spreadsheet Freezer could help me to control when a formula is recalculated. I read on the it's site that I could find the install link here, but I only found questions that point back to the add-on website.

I already searched for it on Google the G Suite Marketplace and the Google Sheets Add-on store.

Related questions

- [Having Google Sheets not recalculate a formula on page load](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123377/88163)
- [Recalculate google sheet on demand:](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/129068/88163)

Related Google Sheets Help article

- [Freeze or merge rows & columns](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9060449?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: I have read the [Can I support my product on this site?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/product-support). I think that I followed all the recommendations there, anyway, feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the Spreadsheet Freezer developer.

---

Update: [Here is the link](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/spreadsheet_freezer/526561533622) to the install page from the G Suite Marketplace

---

I'm sorry, the link has not been added yet on this site. When we do that, this question will be updated. In the mean time you could request the install link by using the [Feedback submission form](https://sites.google.com/rubenrivera.mx/spreadsheet-freezer/feedback) that was added few moments ago. Please don't share the link with others until further notice.

1. Fill the Comments question.
   You could add a link to a related question, share briefly about your interest on **Spreadsheet Freezer** or anything else just follow the same [conduct guidelines of this site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/conduct).
2. Then select Yes, then Next
3. Then wrote your email address
4. Check the check boxes that apply,  minimum 1. Submissions with no options checked could be ignored.
5. Click the submit button.

[image]